# Why are True and False being set in globals by this code?

Tags: python

I was recently [reading some code online](https://code.activestate.com/recipes/221251-maximum-cardinality-matching-in-general-graphs/), and saw this block:

```
if 'True' not in globals():
    globals()['True'] = not None
    globals()['False'] = not True
```

What is happening here? Why would `True` ever not be in globals? I've never come across anything like this during my ~10 years as a professional python programmer!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That code is super duper old, targeting compatibility with Python 2.2. [Back before Python 2.3](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/), there was no `bool` type and no built-in `True` or `False`. You can also see a `from __future__ import generators` future statement up at the top, because generators existed in 2.2, but the syntax [had to be turned on explicitly](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/#specification-yield), because the Python dev team didn't want to introduce a new keyword (`yield`) without a transition period.

Incidentally, this code's author got the compatibility logic wrong. The built-in `True` would have been in the [`__builtin__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) module, not `globals()`, so this code is checking in the wrong place. Fortunately, there are few consequences to accidentally adding redundant bindings for `True` and `False` to `globals()`, as long as you don't do something like `True = False` (which was possible in Python 2).

Comment: no built-in true or false? Why was this design decision ever made?

Comment: so if I am getting this right before booleans in python 1 or 0 was just used. And this was in or around 2001?

Comment: Apparently it's not possible to access `builtins.True` ? https://pastebin.com/cBdipJ5u

Comment: @Chris_Rands: You're on Python 3, where `True` is a keyword. `builtins.True` fails because Python sees a keyword instead of an identifier. (There's still a `True` built-in variable, although I don't think it's needed any more.)

Comment: @Chris_Rands: I think that's just because you screwed up your quotes. You can't use single-quotes inside single-quotes like that.

Comment: @user2357112 facepalm, of course, thanks again! still feels wrong about `builtins.True` being *there* but synatically invalid though